# Primary key UUID Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, primary-key, uuid

I am trying to make a table where the primary key is auto generated UUID every time there's an INSERT event. But the problem is when I try to execute an INSERT query skipping the primary key column like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tablename` (`reference`) VALUES ('hey');
```

No row is inserted and no errors. Just "0 rows inserted..."
Here's my table and the trigger. Thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
    `uuid` char(36) NULL,
    `reference` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (uuid)
);

DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_tablename
BEFORE INSERT ON tablename
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF new.uuid IS NULL THEN
    SET new.uuid = uuid();
  END IF;
END
;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **CAN NOT** make a `Primary key` as `NULL`

Just change it to `NOT NULL`

```
`uuid` char(36) NOT NULL,
```

> The primary key for a table represents the column or set of columns that you use in your most vital queries. It has an associated index, for fast query performance. Query performance benefits from the NOT NULL optimization, because it cannot include any NULL values.

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html)

Comment: I can't believed I missed this one. But when I set it to `NOT NULL` it didn't change anything. And then I figured that my condition in the trigger checks `IF new.uuid IS NULL THEN`. I changed it to something that checks if it is null or an empty string. `IF new.uuid IS NULL OR new.uuid = '' THEN` and it works! Thank you for making me realize.